# Compare Time in Rails without the seconds

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

In my Rails 5 app I want to send an alert 10 minutes after a certain datetime in my database. For example 10 minutes after the created_at datetime.

So I run a cronjob every 1 minute and have to look in my database for all records where created_at was 10 minutes ago.

My created_at field is in the format 2017-06-01 12:00:00. How can I get all records where created_at was 10 minutes ago?

My problem are the seconds and I can't simple do (this is not valid Ruby code, it's just to show my point):

```
where created_at == 10.minutes.ago
```

I would have to do something like

```
where created_at > 10.minutes.ago AND created_at < 9.minutes.ago
```

But this does not seem very clean. Are there better solutions?

Comment: Yep, your range query looks perfectly fine to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to provide range in order to get records..however, to avoid dependencies with seconds, you can do something like below elegantly..

```
range = range = 10.minutes.ago.beginning_of_minute..10.minutes.ago.end_of_minute
records = YourModel.where(created_at: range)
```

Comment: This looks good. Do you know if .. includes or excludes the two borders of the range? depending on that I might have to use end_of_minute.

Comment: `beginning_of_minute` does nothing but sets the value of seconds to `0` and `end_of_minute` to `59`..they both include those values...

Comment: The question is if ".." means > created_at > or > created_at >= or >= created_at >=. Do you know what I mean? I have to avoid that a record gets included in two following ranges.

Comment: I will use 10.minutes.ago.beginning_of_minute..10.minutes.ago.end_of_minute to avoid that e.g. 12:00:00 gets included twice. Would you agree with that? If case I can accept your answer.